# Binding DataSet to DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I know this has been asked before several times but I am not able to get this. 
I have a `DataSet` and a `DataGrid`. All I want to do is display the contents of the `DataSet` in the `DataGrid`.

I have written this code :

```
vConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
vConn.Open();

vQuery = "Select * from Book";

DataSet vDs = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter vAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter(vQuery, vConn);
vAdap.Fill(vDs,"Book");

GridData.DataContext = vDs.Tables["Book"];
vConn.Close();
```

But for some reason the data is not shown on DataGrid. I have tried setting AutoGenerateColumn to True/False. I also tried binding in xaml but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to set your DataTable to the ItemsSource property of DataGrid?

Comment: it says "Cannot implicitly convert `System.Data.DataTable` to `System.Collections.IEnumerable`"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this should work:

```
GridData.ItemsSource = vDs.Tables["Book"].DefaultView;
```

or you can create your own `DataView`:

```
GridData.ItemsSource = new DataView(vDs.Tables["Book"]);
```

`DataTable.DefaultView` gives you [`DataView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) which implements `IEnumerable` and can be used as `ItemsSource`

Comment: @Okuma.Scott `DataTable` must be converted into `DataView` which implements `IEnumerable`. You can bind `DataTable` to `ItemsSource` in XAML but you'll still need `IValueConverter` that will perform that convertion.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just pulling out the table I wanted in code-behind and binding to that. The compiler really should throw an error if you attempt to bind a GridView's ItemsSource to a DataSet directly...

Answer (score 1):

OK, so [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859978/populate-datagrid-using-datacontext-in-c-sharp-wpf) may be the same issue you are dealing with.

You can try to set the `ItemsSource` property as follow:

```
GridData.ItemsSource = vDs.Tables["Book"].AsEnumerable();
```