# Binding treeview and datagrid to dataset with MVVM model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, treeview

I try to make binding both of treeview and datagrid to dataset. I would like when treeviewitem change (rename, add, remove), datagrid and dataset update too. When datagrid change (add row, remove row, rename), treeview and dataset update too.

I can easyly apply it with normal way

for datagrid

.cs

```
public DataView DataView
{
    get { return _dataView; }
    set { _dataView = value; OnPropertyChanged("DataView"); }
}

DataView dv = MainWindow.ds.Tables["Project"].AsDataView();
dv.RowFilter = "ProjectName <> ''";
_dataView = dv;
```

.xaml

```
<DataGrid  Name="dataGridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataView , Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Project Name" Binding="{Binding ProjectName}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Treeview

.cs

```
ds.Relations.Add("Parents", t.Columns["ProjectID"], t.Columns["ParentID"], false);

Root = new DataView(t);
Root.RowFilter = "[ParentID]<0";

public DataView Root { get; private set; }
```

.xaml

```
<TreeView Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding Root}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Now, it's working fine. the binding treeview <-> datagrid <-> dataset is created. If one of them change, other also change

But if I do like this, I can't apply Josh smith's MVVVM to use IsSelected, IsExpand because now MVVM is in system.DataViewRow. If I try to apply Josh smith's MVVM to treeview, the link between treeview and dataset is broken because treeview do not directly use dataset, it use dataset thought viewmodel. When treeview item change (obviously gui update), dataset and datagrid are not changed

How to make MVVM to binding treeview, dataset and datagrid synchonize data?

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16964093/10024696)

Comment: @neeleshbodgal Yes, It's the same with my way to binding datagrid. No problem with datagrid. However, if I binding treeview like this I cannot apply MVVM and don't something like a (parent, selectednode, add, remove node, IsSelected...). If I try to use MVVM, dataset and treeviewItem are divided by ViewModel class (Here is TreeNodeViewModel) and can't binding data with treeview and dataset